# Joomla 3.1. Pull data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

I want to pull data from MySQL. I try this

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select(array($db->quoteName('total_amount')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('money'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadResult();

?>
<?php echo $results; ?>
```

but it gives me a single result. What I want is, to pull all data from the column and put it separately. What is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loadResult()` displays a single result from the database. What you need is `loadObjectList()`.

So you query will be like so:

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select(array($db->quoteName('total_amount')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('money'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

// display the results
foreach ( $results as $result) {
   echo "<p>" . $result->total_amount . "</p>";
}
?>
```

Please note that if the database table you're using is from a Joomla extension and not one you have manually created, then you should use `quoteName('#__money')`. Note the `#__` before the table name.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, it works, but a little thing I cannot catch where it is from. The code returns me all the results but in the very end it also gives me a string "Array". Where is it from?

Comment: I thought you wanted to pull all the results?

Comment: yes, it is, I have something like this: 32000.00
12000.00
50000.00
Array.    I cannot understand where the word array comes from

Comment: I don't think it's coming from the code I gave you as I have fully tested this code. It might be possible that there is a value in the database called "Array". Check the database table and see if there is a value in there called "Array".

Comment: good good :) As this answered your question, please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use `loadObjectList()` instead of `loadResult` and print list of objects with print_r(). More details: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

```
<?php  
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select(array($db->quoteName('total_amount')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('money'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

?>
<?php print_r($results); ?>
```

Comment: this givees me something like this: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [total_amount] => 15000.00 ) and so forth

Comment: Because it is list of objects. You can iterate over it with for.